# Apache HTTP Server has stopped working in Xammp v3.2.1

Tags: xampp

Problem signature:

```
 Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.10.0
  Application Timestamp:    53c79afa
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.23889
  Fault Module Timestamp:   598d4c81
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0002e43e
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Read our privacy statement online:

```
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
```

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:

```
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: What is your question?